# Alienware TactX Mouse does not connect. Device Manager says it has malfunctioned

Tags: mouse

My alieware tactx mouse was working fine a month ago but now is off and does not show up. I have windows 7 64 bit Alienware. Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43) comes up in the description.

Comment: Does it work on another computer?  Aside from that, what's your question exactly?

Comment: It doesn't work on any computer. I was wondering if anyone knew how to fix it.